# jQuery - Show one DIV before certain date, another after

Tags: jquery, date, show-hide

I need to be able to show one div before the new year, and another after the new year - it's a set of certain form elements so I think this is the best way to do it.

Can someone point me in the right direction of syntax?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Can you control this server-side?  This approach won't work well for JavaScript disabled users.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this - would a PHP method be more reliable for this?

Comment: Depends what your goal is...
If it is like @Gaby said something like a special offer from a shop, you should use a server side method. If it is a Happy New Year message, you should use the client side method.

Answer (score 8):

```
   if (new Date() < new Date(2011,1,1))
       $('#before').show();
   else
       $('#after').show();
```

If both are hidden in the beginning.

Comment: The nice thing of this solution in stead of server side, is that it gets automatically "localized" for users' time zone.

Comment: unless of'course you do not want it to be localized :) a special offer from a shop should not be locally effective, for example.. but the code is fine for what the OP asks. +1

Comment: that's great thanks, this may be an ignorant question but where does jQuery get the date from? Is it the user's computer settings?

Comment: new Date() is not a jQuery thing, it's a javascript thing: http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp
Javascript/The browser gets it from the users' system clock.